# Differences between textures?

Tags: textures, udk, 3dsmax, cryengine

Me and a small team of people are creating a video game in UDK. As i have heard, the game engine can only go up to `8192x8192px` textures. In cry Engine 3, you can go up to about `16K px`. Is there a difference in the look of the two textures in the game? Does it depend on the monitor used? I am very new to this, and was just curious. Should i go to the cry Engine, or stick with UDK? Thanks.

Comment: You almost certainly do not need textures anywhere near that size.  I'm unsure what they even do with those (e.g. for 3D texturing or some other use), but many graphics cards can't handle those sizes.  Pick an engine based on content workflow and gameplay-relevant features, not crazy bullet points like texture size.

Comment: Also, "which tech to use" questions are [off-topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i think it´s used for texture atlas in terrain rendering and diffrent type of megatexture solutions.

Comment: You'd be restricting yourself to less than 20% of your target audience if you actually used 16k textures, not that many graphics cards can handle that large of a texture. http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE

Comment: Thank you guys sooo much. I appreciate it. But why does Crysis 3 use those massive textures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a some difference, you will need a very good artist to make it look better from the 8k/8k. It is better to use smaller textures merged using UV mapping.

If you are not a proffesional I'd stick with the smaller resolution. Epic games tries to create a product for the masses, and unless you know how to make a good lightmap it makes no sense to make shorten the game audience, not everyone bothers playing on ultra detail.

As for the use of such high resolution maps, yesterday I played the game Tomb Raider 2013. I used my development pc which has the GTX Titan installed and in one scene Lara Croft picked up a photo of her and it has looked real. Like a normal photo taken by a real life camera. And you don't need an ultra res. Photo to achieve that. You can merge more smaller photos using UV mapping.

Should I stick with Cry Engine or Unreal:

Stay with UDK, better doc's and it is more user friendly, with over more than a milion downloads you can get more help around the game dev.

If you are a team of gamers making games without good 3d modelling experience, it wont make a difference. Unreal4 engine has some features that the Cry Engine lacks. Furthermore, with Cry Engine without paying a large sum you will not have access to the engine source code, which is always easing the development.